# Karate - Sauce labs : Webdriver session create status 401

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, karate, saucelabs

I am unable to execute scripts on saucelabs via my local machine as we are not able to create webdriver session and it returns status 401

I have tried the following :

Changed the path of chrome.exe file as it looks for the file in default path
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"

Also tried adding this to config :

karate.configure('driver', { type: 'chrome', port: 9222, executable: 'C://Program Files//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe' });

None of the above works !

curled the following commands which didnt work

curl -v --proxy http://proxyHost:80 https://ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub/status
curl -v --proxy https://user:password@proxyHost:proxyPort https://ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub/status

Finally tried this :

URL https://ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub/status in a browser and got the below :

{"ready":true,"message":"Sauce Labs automated testing is fully operational"}

update: I do see a tunnel provisioned on sauce labs. However, the browser won't launch as it's not able to create a chrome web driver session

Comment: not a saucelabs expert, but `chrome.exe` should not come into the picture if you are using saucelabs. and you should set `start: false`, read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#webdriverurl - also see other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/karate+saucelabs

Comment: Yes makes sense! start is set to false and I also see a tunnel provisioned on sauce labs

Comment: Thanks, it worked now! Was able to figure out from the karate documentation

Answer (score 2):

As Peter mentioned, chrome.exe will not come into play here as that is only for local execution. Please see the following repo that has a working example of Karate working with Sauce Labs execution: [Karate/Sauce Labs GitHub example](https://github.com/nadvolod/karateSaucelabs)

Comment: Yes makes sense! I was looking for solutions online and someone had mentioned somewhere about having a similar issue and using sauce connect and then changing the path for chrome driver but yes changing the chrome path on the local doesn't really come into play